# Power BI: shifting a column one row above

Tags: powerbi

I have a case that I want find the duration for each "state_id", by subtracting its **change_time** from the time just below it.

So I want to generate a new column that duplicates the column **"change_time"** and shifting all values one row up, so the **change_time** #2(in red) would come next to **change_time** #3(in red).

Is there a way to shift that column one row up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of thinking and researching. I have solved it with the following steps:

- Sort you columns of interest from A-Z (in my case sort: ticket_id, then history_type_id, then stat_id)
- make a first new index column starting from 0 using "Index column from 0".
- make a second new index column starting from 1 using "Index column from 1".
- merge your query with itself using "merge query" based in the two new indices.
- expand the merged query for the date column only.
  Now you will have a new date column, duplicated from the old one with a shift of one row.

1. 

[image]

2)
[image]